# Templates are not removed once they are replaced

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

So I have been using meteor for a while and after the 0.8 update a large amount of my templates are failing, because previously rendered are active in the background. How can I remove templates with Blaze?

I'm getting a flickering effect (Template renders and re-renders 4-5 times really fast.)

Comment: Can you post some of your code? How are you rendering templates? For example, template instances driven by reactive data sources like database cursors should be automatically removed as the data source changes. If you are manually using `UI.insert` and `UI.render` (not needed for the majority of applications), then you need to do additional work to remove the rendered DOM elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to switch back to Iron Router, which works waaay better than my small hashtag route based system.